# Dropdownlist menu of Metro UI CSS in asp page inside sub folder doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a problem. I have one application asp.net in C# and I use Metro UI CSS for Dropdownlist menu. My problem is that Dropdownlist menu work properly with the pages in the same folder with the master page but when I use the same master page with a asp page in a sub folder Dropdownlist menu doesn't work.

It give an error on Google Chrome: Filed to load resources the server responded with a status of 404 (not found). This error come for all the .js file  and .css.

Any help will be appreciate.

Here is the script I include in the head of mys master page

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/docs.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="js/metro.min.js"></script>


<link href="css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/iconFont.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="fonts/iconFont.dev.svg" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/iconFont.eot" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/iconFont.json" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/iconFont.svg" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/iconFont.ttf" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/iconFont.woff" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="fonts/" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/metroSysIcons.svg" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/metroSysIcons.ttf" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fonts/metroSysIcons.woff" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

My problem is that I can use dropdownlist menu in .aspx pages which are in the main where the Master page is but when I put another .aspx in a sub folder using the same master page the dropdownlist menu doesn't work. I use Metro UI CSS.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Put your related code here. So that we can help you. From your description we don't have any idea what actually happening in your code base.

Comment: Here is the script I have include in the head of my master page.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ResolveClientUrl`. Put all your js file in one folder and link them to master page in this way

```
<script src="<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is also applicable for css files.

```
<link href="<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/css/metro-bootstrap.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
```